# Travis build fails because of lint saying that SDK platform-tools version is too old

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-lint

Hi I have an android app I build on Travis CI. Unfortunately the build fails, because lint says that the platform sdk tools are too old:

> The SDK platform-tools version (23.0.1) is too old  to check APIs compiled with API 25; please update

The build tools I use (in build.gradle file) is `25.0.1` and I compile with API 25. On my local machine my app compiles fine from command line without any lint errors.

My `.travis.yml` file looks like this:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
  - tools
  - build-tools-25.0.1
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - android-25
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
licenses:
- android-sdk-license-.+
- android-sdk-license-c81a61d9
```

Any idea what could be wrong with my travis settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `platform-tools` to your `components:` block. I have it listed first in my `.travis.yml`:

```
android:
    components:
        - platform-tools
        - tools
        - build-tools-25.0.1
        - android-25
        - extra-android-m2repository
        - extra-android-support
        - extra-google-m2repository
        - extra-google-google_play_services
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Travis has such issue that's not yet resolved: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6699

Going from there I found a workaround that worked for me - you need to duplicate `android` and `build-tools` sections as below, with the version you need. It's said this way Travis gets the right versions: https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android/pull/789

```
...
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - android-24
    - build-tools-24.0.2
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-24.0.2
    - android-24
...
```